# FLEX: Is there a way to return multiple tokens at once

Tags: regex, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

In flex, I want to return multiple tokens for one match of a regular expression.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The way I've been doing this is to create a queue of to-be-returned tokens, and at the beginning of `yylex()`, check for tokens and return them.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Do you mean all matches? Are you using regex functions or string functions? Use the global flag.</s>

As for flex, I don't think you can do that. You test for a match with one pattern at a time so that's probably out of scope. Why'd you want that? As an optimization? Scoping issues?

Comment: To be honest, I am fairly new to flex and I am not sure.  I thought I was using a combination of regular expressions and string matching.

Here is an example
"("      { return L_PAREN; }
{INT}       { yylval.Int = atoi(yytext); return INT; }

What I want is to be able to return two tokens at once.

Answer (score -1):

Usually, this is handled by a parser on top of the scanner which gives you much cleaner code.  You can emulate that to some degree with states:

```
%option noyywrap

%top {
#define TOKEN_LEFT_PAREN    4711
#define TOKEN_RIGHT_PAREN   4712
#define TOKEN_NUMBER        4713
}

%x PAREN_STATE
%%
"("         BEGIN(PAREN_STATE); return TOKEN_LEFT_PAREN;
<PAREN_STATE>{
   [0-9]+   return TOKEN_NUMBER;
   ")"      BEGIN(INITIAL); return TOKEN_RIGHT_PAREN;
   .|\n     /* maybe signal syntax error here */
}
%%
int main (int argc, char *argv [])
{
  int i;

  while ((i = yylex ()))
    printf ("%d\n", i);

  return 0;
}
```

but this will get very messy as soon as your grammar gets more complex.

Comment: Fascinating.  I'm sure at one point this answer had a score of 10 or more for many years, but in the past, hmmm, six months it has gone negative without any indication why.